# Comparing Tagged Types

Tags: ada, gnat

In Java, one would use the `instanceof` in order to check if an object is of the same type (or class-wide type) as another object. For instance, if we have the class `Peach` and an object `peach`, it would through the following:

```
if (peach instanceof Peach)
    System.out.println("peach is of type Peach!");
```

... execute the statement above into the terminal.

From what I remember, in Ada, there is something along the lines of `is in`, as in that some object is inside a certain class-wide set. Brilliantly enough, however, I cannot seem to find information on the subject for the purpose of this question. Last time I used the `is in`, I couldn't get it to work. As such, I decided to ask the question on here instead.

Any pointers as to how comparison of tagged types might be done in a similar manner to that of Java's `instanceof` would be very helpful!

Comment: One way : look at the tags. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Attributes/%27Tag

Comment: @BrianDrummond Interesting! I don't think I've ever heard of the `'Tag` attribute in Ada, but it's looking really promising!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

just `in`, not `is in`

```
if Foo in Peach'Class then
```